# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t[Yn] is not a function

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, lightning-web-components

I am getting this error when trying to write the below-mentioned logic.

```
<template>
    <div class="form-group">
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" list="valueList" name="searchterm" placeholder="Describe your issue">
        <datalist id="valueList">
            <template for:each={listOfarticles} for:item='item'>
                <option key={item.key} value={item.key}>{item.value}</option>
            </template>
        </datalist>
    </div>
</template>



import { wire , track} from 'lwc';
import externalScripts from 'c/externalScripts';
import fetchAllKnowledgeArticles from '@salesforce/apex/UtilityClass.fetchAllKnowledgeArticles';
export default class SearchArticle extends externalScripts {
    /* eslint-disable no-console */
    @track searchKeyWord;
    @track listOfarticles;
    initializedKnowledge = false;

    @wire(fetchAllKnowledgeArticles , {SiteName:'ENGLISH', notDisplayFor: 'Logged in' } )
        wiredContacts({data, error}){
            if(data){
                this.listOfarticles = data;
                console.log('---knowledgeArticle----');
                console.log(data);
                //this.error = undefined;
            }
            else if (error) {
                //this.error  error;
                console.log('error');
                console.log(error);
                //this.accounts = undefined;
            }
        }

    renderedCallback() {
        if (this.initializedKnowledge) {
            return;
        }
        this.initializedKnowledge = true;
        let listId = this.template.querySelector('datalist').id;
        console.log('Test');
        console.log(listId);
        this.template.querySelector("input").setAttribute("list", listId);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Your comment on my answer includes information that would have been relevant to include in the original question. As it stands, we probably don't have enough information to help you. You may want to [edit] your question.